# dnsmasq refuses query after reboot

Tags: dnsmasq

`dnsmasq` is started by the gnome network manager using the config option `dns=dnsmasq` however my dns is broken until I run `service network-manager restart` and doing `dig google.com @localhost` shows that `dnsmasq` is refusing queries but after I restart network manager queries work fine. What is causing dnsmasq to refuse queries after a reboot and how can I fix it? If nothing else what's a good way to cause the network-manager service to be restarted when I login?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I figured it out. I had to go into network manager and disable IPv6. I'm assuming I had to do that because IPv6 is disabled at a kernel level for me since it doesn't seem to play nicely with my network for some reason. It's weird because without dnsmasq I can leave the IPv6 section of network manager configured and everything works fine but I guess dnsmasq doesn't like it.