# dnsmasq not working after reboot

Tags: dns, services, reboot, dnsmasq

After rebooting, dnsmasq service is running, but does not respond to remote requests (trying using "dig @10.0.0.1 stackexchange.com" from another machine). The log looks good in my opinion:

```
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname systemd[1]: Starting dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server...
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[488]: dnsmasq: syntax check OK.
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[530]: started, version 2.76 cachesize 150
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[530]: compile time options: IPv6 GNU-getopt DBus i18n IDN DHCP DHCPv6 no-Lua TFTP conntrack ips
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[530]: DNS service limited to local subnets
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[530]: using nameserver 208.67.222.222#53
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[530]: using nameserver 208.67.220.220#53
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname dnsmasq[530]: read /etc/hosts - 5 addresses
Aug 11 17:41:04 srvname systemd[1]: Started dnsmasq - A lightweight DHCP and caching DNS server.
Aug 11 17:41:21 srvname dnsmasq[530]: Ignoring query from non-local network
```

I have no idea where the last line comes from but it is there immediately after reboot before I do anything.

If I restart the dnsmasq service, I get the same log entries except for the last line and then it is reachable for all machines on the network - all is fine.

dnsmasq config:

```
domain-needed
bogus-priv
no-resolv
server=208.67.220.220
server=208.67.222.222
address=/homeserver.mydomain.com/10.0.0.99
```

The last line is so that machines on my local network will be able to find the server itself using its domain name. My internet router won't forward requests for homeserver.mydomain.com from the local network to 10.0.0.99 on its own (this is a feature some routers have and some (like mine) do not).

In addition to this config I filter out malware servers from a list.

relevant iptables config (iptables-persistent file):

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
```

I have found two possible solutions so far, however I don't know how to implement them:

- [in an earlier question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/311739/dnsmasq-refuses-query-after-reboot) someone mentions that disabling IPv6 helped them with a similar issue. However, I am not sure how to do that.
- A friend suggested that the order in which the services are started might be the issue and to move dnsmasq to the end so it starts last. However, I am also not sure how to modify this. What I tried already was to put into /etc/network/interfaces the following line: "post-up /usr/sbin/service dnsmasq restart" (attempting to force the reboot after the network comes up). However, that did not help either.

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Kernel: Linux 4.9.0-8-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.110-3+deb9u4 (2018-08-21) x86_64 GNU/Linux
Hardware: Asus VivoMini Intel N3000

Comment: Please add info about your config to your question -- you can get it `egrep -hrv '^#|^$' /etc/dnsmasq.*`  (of course, edit out any sensitive stuff). Try adding `except-interface=ethX` to the config (where ethX is an interface you don't need dnsmasq to listen on) -- the errors suggest that `local-service` is in effect and the machine you're querying from is not on the same subnet.

Comment: @mosvy: I added details. I only have one eth-interface and all machines are on the same subnet, so I don't think this is the issue.

Comment: For one reason or another, dnsmasq seems to believe that they're not on the same subnet -- that's what should be investigated. In the meanwhile, you could try adding `interface=you_ethX` to the config. Read about `--local-service` in the manpage for how it interacts with `except-interface` and `interface` ( the `--local-service` option is given directly on the command line of dnsmasq in debian, have a look at `/etc/init.d/dnsmasq`).

Comment: Please notice that you can use `except-interface` with an interface that doesn't exist, eg. `except-interface=no_such_if` will also turn off the `local-service` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

adding `interface=eth0` to dnsmasq.conf as suggested by mosvy solved the issue.